# windows 10 rdp keeps disconnecting immediately - "Another user has logged in"

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

Windows 10 pro 64 bit

I installed it on a virtual machine.

I created a user account without a password. This is just a test bench so security isnt a concern.

I also changed the group policy to allow rdp connections with blank passwords.

Well every time I rdp into the vm, I immediately get kicked out.

"Another user connected to the remote computer so your connection was lost"

Why does it keep kicking me out? Its a fresh VM that no one but me has access to.

Answer (score -1):

Disregard. Duplicate.

> Go to Start > All Programs > Administrative Tools > Remote Desktop
> Services > Remote Desktop Session Host configuration. Double-click the
> setting "Restrict each user to a single session" and change it to no.
> Voila!

[How to stop a remote desktop session from ending](https://superuser.com/questions/691191/how-to-stop-a-remote-desktop-session-from-ending/696622#696622)